# C# Cant hide label on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting an error when trying to add code to hide the label on a button click.

```
    private void VehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.vehiclesBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.ABCDataSet);
        bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Visible = true;
        vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Visible = false;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Vehicle Saved");
        regTextBox.Visible = false;
        makeTextBox.Visible = false;
        modelTextBox.Visible = false;
        last_MileageTextBox.Visible = false;
        mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = false;
        tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = false;
        retiredTextBox.Visible = false;
        regLabel.Visible = false;
    }
```

**Error:**

> Error CS0103  The name 'regLabel' does not exist in the current context

regLabel from Designer:

```
        // 
        // regLabel
        // 
        regLabel.AutoSize = true;
        regLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 46);
        regLabel.Name = "regLabel";
        regLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 13);
        regLabel.TabIndex = 2;
        regLabel.Text = "Reg:";
```

**Form CS file:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ABC
{
    public partial class NewVehicle : Form
    {
        public NewVehicle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void VehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.vehiclesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.ABCDataSet);
            bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Visible = true;
            vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Visible = false;
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Vehicle Saved");
            regTextBox.Visible = false;
            makeTextBox.Visible = false;
            modelTextBox.Visible = false;
            last_MileageTextBox.Visible = false;
            mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = false;
            tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = false;
            retiredTextBox.Visible = false;
            regLabel.Visible = false;
        }

        private void NewVehicle_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'ABCDataSet.Vehicles' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            this.vehiclesTableAdapter.Fill(this.ABCDataSet.Vehicles);

        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.vehiclesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.ABCDataSet);
        }

        private void CloseNewVehicle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            regTextBox.Visible = true;
            makeTextBox.Visible = true;
            modelTextBox.Visible = true;
            last_MileageTextBox.Visible = true;
            mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = true;
            tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = true;
            retiredTextBox.Visible = true;
            regLabel.Visible = true;
            bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Visible = false;
            vehiclesBindingSource.AddNew();
            retiredTextBox.Text = Properties.Settings.Default.retireddefault;
            vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Visible = true;
        }

        private void regTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void vehiclesBindingNavigator_RefreshItems(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void vehiclesBindingSource_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**Form Designer CS file:**

```
using System;

namespace ABC
{
    partial class NewVehicle
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            System.Windows.Forms.Label regLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label makeLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label modelLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label last_MileageLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label mOT_Expiry_DateLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label tAX_Expiry_DateLabel;
            System.Windows.Forms.Label retiredLabel;
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(NewVehicle));
            this.vehiclesBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
            this.ABCDataSet = new ABC.ABCDataSet();
            this.vehiclesTableAdapter = new ABC.ABCDataSetTableAdapters.VehiclesTableAdapter();
            this.tableAdapterManager = new ABC.ABCDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager();
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel();
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem = new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton();
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator(this.components);
            this.regTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.makeTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.modelTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.last_MileageTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
            this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker = new System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker();
            this.retiredTextBox = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            regLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            makeLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            modelLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            last_MileageLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            mOT_Expiry_DateLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            tAX_Expiry_DateLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            retiredLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vehiclesBindingSource)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ABCDataSet)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vehiclesBindingNavigator)).BeginInit();
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // regLabel
            // 
            regLabel.AutoSize = true;
            regLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 46);
            regLabel.Name = "regLabel";
            regLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 13);
            regLabel.TabIndex = 2;
            regLabel.Text = "Reg:";
            // 
            // makeLabel
            // 
            makeLabel.AutoSize = true;
            makeLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(58, 72);
            makeLabel.Name = "makeLabel";
            makeLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(37, 13);
            makeLabel.TabIndex = 4;
            makeLabel.Text = "Make:";
            // 
            // modelLabel
            // 
            modelLabel.AutoSize = true;
            modelLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(56, 98);
            modelLabel.Name = "modelLabel";
            modelLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(39, 13);
            modelLabel.TabIndex = 6;
            modelLabel.Text = "Model:";
            // 
            // last_MileageLabel
            // 
            last_MileageLabel.AutoSize = true;
            last_MileageLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(25, 124);
            last_MileageLabel.Name = "last_MileageLabel";
            last_MileageLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 13);
            last_MileageLabel.TabIndex = 8;
            last_MileageLabel.Text = "Last Mileage:";
            // 
            // mOT_Expiry_DateLabel
            // 
            mOT_Expiry_DateLabel.AutoSize = true;
            mOT_Expiry_DateLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 151);
            mOT_Expiry_DateLabel.Name = "mOT_Expiry_DateLabel";
            mOT_Expiry_DateLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(91, 13);
            mOT_Expiry_DateLabel.TabIndex = 9;
            mOT_Expiry_DateLabel.Text = "MOT Expiry Date:";
            // 
            // tAX_Expiry_DateLabel
            // 
            tAX_Expiry_DateLabel.AutoSize = true;
            tAX_Expiry_DateLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(7, 177);
            tAX_Expiry_DateLabel.Name = "tAX_Expiry_DateLabel";
            tAX_Expiry_DateLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(88, 13);
            tAX_Expiry_DateLabel.TabIndex = 11;
            tAX_Expiry_DateLabel.Text = "TAX Expiry Date:";
            // 
            // retiredLabel
            // 
            retiredLabel.AutoSize = true;
            retiredLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(51, 202);
            retiredLabel.Name = "retiredLabel";
            retiredLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(44, 13);
            retiredLabel.TabIndex = 13;
            retiredLabel.Text = "Retired:";
            // 
            // vehiclesBindingSource
            // 
            this.vehiclesBindingSource.DataMember = "Vehicles";
            this.vehiclesBindingSource.DataSource = this.ABCDataSet;
            this.vehiclesBindingSource.CurrentChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.vehiclesBindingSource_CurrentChanged);
            // 
            // ABCDataSet
            // 
            this.ABCDataSet.DataSetName = "ABCDataSet";
            this.ABCDataSet.SchemaSerializationMode = System.Data.SchemaSerializationMode.IncludeSchema;
            // 
            // vehiclesTableAdapter
            // 
            this.vehiclesTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
            // 
            // tableAdapterManager
            // 
            this.tableAdapterManager.BackupDataSetBeforeUpdate = false;
            this.tableAdapterManager.ConsumablesTableAdapter = null;
            this.tableAdapterManager.EmployeesTableAdapter = null;
            this.tableAdapterManager.HolidaysTableAdapter = null;
            this.tableAdapterManager.ServicesTableAdapter = null;
            this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateOrder = ABC.ABCDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager.UpdateOrderOption.InsertUpdateDelete;
            this.tableAdapterManager.VehiclesTableAdapter = this.vehiclesTableAdapter;
            // 
            // bindingNavigatorCountItem
            // 
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.None;
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem.Enabled = false;
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem.Name = "bindingNavigatorCountItem";
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 37);
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem.Text = "of {0}";
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem.ToolTipText = "Total number of items";
            // 
            // vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem
            // 
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Image")));
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Name = "vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem";
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(68, 37);
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Text = "Save";
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Visible = false;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.VehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click);
            // 
            // bindingNavigatorAddNewItem
            // 
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Image")));
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.ImageScaling = System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemImageScaling.None;
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Name = "bindingNavigatorAddNewItem";
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.RightToLeftAutoMirrorImage = true;
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(133, 37);
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Text = "Add New Vehicle";
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click);
            // 
            // vehiclesBindingNavigator
            // 
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.AddNewItem = null;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.BindingSource = this.vehiclesBindingSource;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.CountItem = this.bindingNavigatorCountItem;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.DeleteItem = null;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] {
            this.bindingNavigatorCountItem,
            this.bindingNavigatorAddNewItem,
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem});
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.MoveFirstItem = null;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.MoveLastItem = null;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.MoveNextItem = null;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.MovePreviousItem = null;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.Name = "vehiclesBindingNavigator";
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.PositionItem = null;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(317, 40);
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.TabIndex = 0;
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.Text = "bindingNavigator1";
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.RefreshItems += new System.EventHandler(this.vehiclesBindingNavigator_RefreshItems);
            // 
            // regTextBox
            // 
            this.regTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.vehiclesBindingSource, "Reg", true));
            this.regTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 43);
            this.regTextBox.Name = "regTextBox";
            this.regTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.regTextBox.TabIndex = 3;
            this.regTextBox.Visible = false;
            this.regTextBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.regTextBox_TextChanged);
            // 
            // makeTextBox
            // 
            this.makeTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.vehiclesBindingSource, "Make", true));
            this.makeTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 69);
            this.makeTextBox.Name = "makeTextBox";
            this.makeTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.makeTextBox.TabIndex = 5;
            this.makeTextBox.Visible = false;
            // 
            // modelTextBox
            // 
            this.modelTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.vehiclesBindingSource, "Model", true));
            this.modelTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 95);
            this.modelTextBox.Name = "modelTextBox";
            this.modelTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.modelTextBox.TabIndex = 7;
            this.modelTextBox.Visible = false;
            // 
            // last_MileageTextBox
            // 
            this.last_MileageTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.vehiclesBindingSource, "Last Mileage", true));
            this.last_MileageTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 121);
            this.last_MileageTextBox.Name = "last_MileageTextBox";
            this.last_MileageTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.last_MileageTextBox.TabIndex = 9;
            this.last_MileageTextBox.Visible = false;
            // 
            // mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker
            // 
            this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", this.vehiclesBindingSource, "MOT Expiry Date", true));
            this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 147);
            this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Name = "mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker";
            this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20);
            this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.TabIndex = 10;
            this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = false;
            // 
            // tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker
            // 
            this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", this.vehiclesBindingSource, "TAX Expiry Date", true));
            this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 173);
            this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Name = "tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker";
            this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 20);
            this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.TabIndex = 12;
            this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker.Visible = false;
            // 
            // retiredTextBox
            // 
            this.retiredTextBox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", this.vehiclesBindingSource, "Retired", true));
            this.retiredTextBox.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 199);
            this.retiredTextBox.Name = "retiredTextBox";
            this.retiredTextBox.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);
            this.retiredTextBox.TabIndex = 14;
            this.retiredTextBox.Visible = false;
            this.retiredTextBox.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.retiredTextBox_TextChanged);
            // 
            // NewVehicle
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = System.Windows.Forms.ImageLayout.None;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(317, 232);
            this.Controls.Add(retiredLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.retiredTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(tAX_Expiry_DateLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker);
            this.Controls.Add(mOT_Expiry_DateLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker);
            this.Controls.Add(last_MileageLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.last_MileageTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(modelLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.modelTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(makeLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.makeTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(regLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.regTextBox);
            this.Controls.Add(this.vehiclesBindingNavigator);
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.MinimizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "NewVehicle";
            this.Text = "Cowan Transport Management System - New Vehicle";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.NewVehicle_Load);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vehiclesBindingSource)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.ABCDataSet)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.vehiclesBindingNavigator)).EndInit();
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.vehiclesBindingNavigator.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        private void retiredTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }



        private void CloseAmendVehicle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #endregion

        private ABCDataSet ABCDataSet;
        private System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource vehiclesBindingSource;
        private ABCDataSetTableAdapters.VehiclesTableAdapter vehiclesTableAdapter;
        private ABCDataSetTableAdapters.TableAdapterManager tableAdapterManager;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripLabel bindingNavigatorCountItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton vehiclesBindingNavigatorSaveItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton bindingNavigatorAddNewItem;
        private System.Windows.Forms.BindingNavigator vehiclesBindingNavigator;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox regTextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox makeTextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox modelTextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox last_MileageTextBox;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker mOT_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker;
        private System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker tAX_Expiry_DateDateTimePicker;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox retiredTextBox;
    }
}
```

Comment: well thats because there is no control called rLabel in this form. Either you didnt define a label at all, or you gave it a different name

Comment: can you post code from the designer file in regards to `rLabel`

Comment: expand the black arrow on your code file in the solution explorer. If your form was named `Form1` you would have a file named `Form1.cs` and a designer file called `Form1.Designer.cs`

Comment: @IcollectInternetpoints added in question

Comment: hmm, might need more context, can you paste the entire non-designer .cs file or use [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/) and reply with the link?

Comment: hard to tell with the current code you have posted currently, but  probably you are creating the label (dynamically)  in code behind at each page load at some point "after" the click event handler ?

Comment: @IcollectInternetpoints added to question

Comment: @DaniDev How can i see if that is the case?

Comment: Do you get the same error in the Button1_Click method?

Comment: @LarsTech yes same error

Comment: what file name does `rLabel` reside in?

Comment: Are you able to find `rTextBox` in your `Designer.cs`  ?  If yes , then surely you are missing `private System.Windows.Forms.Label rLabel;`

Comment: there is no magic here. ITs just code - some of it generated by VS. You are saying 'set something on the member variable rLable' - VS says, 'I cant see anything with that name'. Are you sure you have it spelled correctly. I think if you had `private` on the label you would get a different error but check it anyway (properties of the label in the designer)

Comment: Have you tried performing a clean, and then building again?  Something might be getting cached by the build process.  It you type "this." and look at the IntelliSense suggestions, is rLabel in the list of options?

Comment: @IcollectInternetpoints What do you mean by file name, project name? or solution name? or something else

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir Yes rTextBox works fine

Comment: are you able to `Go to Definition` of `rLabel`

Comment: @LordWilmore Clean and rebuild done, still the same error

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir How can i do that if it gives an error?

Comment: @pm100 yes spelled correctly, how can i add private to the label to test?

Comment: You are right , that means `rLabel' doesn't exists.Will suggest you to create a new label to fulfill your need.

Comment: @EhsanUllahNazir I have created a new label on its own (not auto created with textbox like the other one) and called it rLabelt. I still get the same error with the new label

Comment: Can you please attach, or otherwise provide, the full .cs and .designer.cs files to this issue, so that I can load them up myself?

Comment: @LordWilmore the files just for the form that its in?

Comment: Yes, if you provide the .cs and .designer.cs files for this form then we will be able to provide more information.  Otherwise we're really just guessing

Comment: @LordWilmore Form.cs and Designer.cs added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conclusion**

Change then label property `GenerateMember` to true.

For labels, it's usually true by default but if drag an object from Data Sources Window and drop it on form, the designer will set `GenerateMember` property for those labels to false.

[More information about `GenerateMember` property.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-the-modifiers-and-generatemember-properties)

---

---

Because you define and declare your `regLablel` inside `InitializeComponent` method. Move it definition outside to the rest of definitions at the end of the file:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Label regLabel;
```

Then inside `InitializeComponents()` method just do this:

```
this.regLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
```

After that change this:

```
 regLabel.AutoSize = true;
 regLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 46);
 regLabel.Name = "regLabel";
 regLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 13);
 regLabel.TabIndex = 2;
 regLabel.Text = "Reg:";
```

To

```
 this.regLabel.AutoSize = true;
 this.regLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(65, 46);
 this.regLabel.Name = "regLabel";
 this.regLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30, 13);
 this.regLabel.TabIndex = 2;
 this.regLabel.Text = "Reg:";
```

Comment: I don't know. When i drag and drop my lable from toolbox to form in designer its definition creates outside InitializeComponents() at the end of the file. Maybe you make some changes in your designer code?

Comment: Ok I know why. At designer you must change property: GenerateMember to false then labels are defined inside InitializeComponents() methods and after that my code looks like yours.

Comment: I don't know when, but probably you drag'n'drop your label to form in designer and change that property from designer (u know label properties F4). And maybe next labels you create by copy that firs label and only change name? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-use-the-modifiers-and-generatemember-properties

Comment: In your case it is Label property. Form doesn't even have GenerateMember property

Comment: @Matt You should mention [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48523402/3110834) which you used for conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

The code you have posted for the form.designer.cs class seems to be (partially?) generated by hand and not by designer.

`System.Windows.Forms.Label regLabel` is a local variable to the `InitializeComponent` method, while designer should create it as a member variable of your Form inherited class. The same for the following controls `makeLabel`, `modeLabel` and so on

Try to manually move the declaration of controls outside the `InitializeComponent` method, as member variables, and after then... never manually edit that file

Comment: Can you try adding a new Label "textLabel" using designer? where does the designer put the declaration? inside the InitializeComponent or as a member variable?

Answer (score 1):

It's because `GenerateMember` property is set to `false` in design time and as a result, a member field is not generated for the control.

Don't touch the generated code, instead, open the form in design mode, and then select `regLabel` at design time. In property grid, select `GenerateMember` property and set it to `true`.

**Note**: For labels, it's usually true by default but if drag an object from `Data Sources Window` and drop it on form, the designer will set `GenerateMember` property for those labels to false.

Comment: For labels, it's usually true by default but if drag an object from `Data Sources Window` and drop it on form, the designer will set `GenerateMember` property for those labels to false.

Comment: @RezaAghaei im going to add that to my accepted answer as its relevant.

Comment: It's better to do it by referencing the answer. It's not good idea if you just copy and paste it. It may mislead some users in future and they may think one answer is just a copy of another one!